# ESP8266 creates AP without any code

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I can't for the life of me figure out why my ESP8266s create WiFi access points.

I plug it in and send an empty sketch, and it creates an AP called "ESP_28F2F8" and here the ESP is at `192.168.4.1`.

I do not want it to create a WiFi network. I just want it to connect to one.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is this perhaps some weird OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal operation of the underlying Espressif's SDK. It remembers some of the settings in flash, like the last created AP and last WiFi network connected.

You need to run

```cpp
WiFi.softAPdisconnect(true);
```

so the ESP disconnects all clients currently connected to it, disables AP and remembers it to flash.

---

If you might also need to disable automatic connection to the last WiFi network, you need to call:

```cpp
WiFi.setAutoConnect(false);
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll try this. Thanks! I'll let you know when I've tried this.

Comment: This worked and fixed my confusion as to why it did this without me telling it should. Many thanks!